# Why is this Python code giving me an error about indentation when the indentation is perfectly correct

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm probably gonna get tons of downvotes on this one but I've tried indenting everything again in the code. I am still, for some reason getting an `IndendationError: expected an indentation block` error which is driving me nuts. I have tried indenting my code again in spaces and tabs but to no avail. Here is the code provided below:

```
async def menu(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()

    embed = discord.Embed(
            title = "Heartbeat Menu",
            description = "Select and enter a number.\n 1. Check Status of Heartbeat\n 2. Hearbeat Check"
        )
    sent = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    
    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel and msg.content in ["1", "2"]
    msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)

    if msg.content == "1":
        #code for number 1
    else:
        #code for number 2
```

The error is on the else statement on the last line. The exact error is:

```
else:   
^ IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I am writing a `Python` bot via the discord library (rewrite version) for a bit of context about the actual code itself.

Comment: Let's get this out of the way to begin with: if the Python interpreter says you have an indentation error, then your indentation is not "perfectly correct". It has an error.

Comment: In this case, the error tells you exactly what the problem is: "expected an indented block". You wrote only a comment, which is not an indented block; comments are ignored by the interpreter. If you want to do nothing in that block, you can write `pass`.

Comment: With regards to `#code for number 1` and `#code for number 2`, do you actually have code there or is it just comments? If it's just comments, then instead put `pass` and see if you still get the error.

Comment: @Haris is it possible that somewhere you have used tab instead of 4 spaces?

Comment: @kaya3 in Python 3, `...` (the ellipsis literal) can be a nice alternative to `pass`, easier to type and a very common placeholder for "nothing here" outside of Python. It's also used in typing files (`.pyi`) to elide function bodies.

Comment: I tried using the `pass` statement, it did resolve the error but now I'm getting a completely different error which states that `await` is outside function on `msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)` these errors have to be connected with indentation right?

Comment: @Masklinn Yes, I tend to use `...` when the code is missing because I haven't written it yet, and `pass` when the block is intentionally empty.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error because there is no code block in else statement. You should write code after if and else statement, or if you decide to write the code later, add a pass statement and everything will work fine.

```
if msg.content == "1":
   #code for number 1
   pass
else:
   #code for number 2
   pass
```

Thanks to @thomas for bringing this to my attention.
You are getting this error on else statement because there is no code following the if statement

Comment: I don't think this is the reason for the error as the indention error is stated for the line with else. I am sure the author of the question has some code for the branches. Missing pass leads to an indention error inside the next line. So at least you can add a pass to the if statement